# Django NoReverseMatch using templates (again)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Second time posting about NoReverseMatch. I just can't seem to understand the error good enough to find the error in my code. Last time it was because I did not give the fields in my url regex a name, but now that's not the issue. I understand that a million things can go wrong but for some reason I just can't seem to find it.

The error is:

> NoReverseMatch at /david/Physics/a/
>   Reverse for 'information' with keyword arguments '{'category_name': 'Physics', 'information_name': 'Test info', 'subcategory_name': 'a'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['david/(?P[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P[a-zA-Z_]+)/$']

The template causing the error is:

```
<h1>The items for {{ category }}/{{ subcategory }}</h1>
{% if items %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'information' category_name=category subcategory_name=subcategory information_name=item %}">{{ item }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h4>No items for that subcategory</h4>
{% endif %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse 

from .models import Category, Subcategory, Information

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basic_web/index.html')

def search(request):
    return HttpResponse('Here you can search!')

def browse(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'basic_web/browse.html', context)

def view_category(request, category_name):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,name__iexact=category_name)
    subcategories = get_list_or_404(Subcategory, parent=category)
    context = {'category': str(category), 'subcategories': map(str, subcategories)}
    return render(request, 'basic_web/category.html', context)

def view_subcategory(request, category_name, subcategory_name):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,name__iexact=category_name)
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategory, name__iexact=subcategory_name, parent=category)
    items = get_list_or_404(Information, subcategory=subcategory, category=category)
    context = {'category': str(category), 'subcategory': str(subcategory), 'items': map(str,items)}
    return render(request, 'basic_web/subcategory.html', context)

def view_information(request, category_name, subcategory_name, information_name):
#    category = get_object_or_404(Category,name__iexcat=category_name)
#    subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategory, name__iexact=subcategory_name, parent=category)
#    information = get_object_or_404(Information, name__iexact=information_name, parent=subcategory)
    return HttpResponse('{0} {1} {2}'.format(category_name, subcategory_name, information_name))
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^browse/$', views.browse, name='browse'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$', views.view_category, name='category'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<subcategory_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$',
        views.view_subcategory, name='subcategory'),
    url(
    r'^(?P<category_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<subcategory_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<information_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$',
        views.view_information, name='information'),
    ]
```

I would also very appreciate if you could give me some tips on how to recognise what is actually wrong when Django says NoReverseMatch

Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you be so kind as to mark the answer as correct. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your URL definition.

```
r'^(?P<category_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<subcategory_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/(?P<information_name>[a-zA-Z_]+)/$',
    views.view_information, name='information'),
```

As far as I can see it does not allow spaces in the url. But you apparently do have a space in one of your values

```
'{'category_name': 'Physics', 'information_name': 'Test info', 'subcategory_name': 'a'}'
```

Comment: You are all magicians, I feel bad to come back here all the time but you guys always deliver. Thank you so much! any tips for how to approach NoReverseMatch ?

Comment: As for  tips, I recommend a reread of the relevent section of the manual :-)